# Can PIC18XXX go into deep sleep?

Tags: embedded, sleep, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am learning about deep sleep mode so I downloaded the following [project](http://embeddedcodesource.com/developer/microchip_technology_59/deep_sleep) to see an examples of deep sleep. The code was written for PIC18F46J50 however I have [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778e.pdf). I was looking at the code and I noticed the following configuration settings relating that PIC.

```
Deep Sleep BOR:
 DSBOREN = OFF
 Disabled  
DSBOREN = ON
 Enabled  

Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer:
 DSWDTEN = OFF
 Disabled  
DSWDTEN = ON
 Enabled  

Deep Sleep Watchdog Postscaler:
 DSWDTPS = 2
 1:2 (2.1 ms)  
DSWDTPS = 8
 1:8 (8.3 ms)  
DSWDTPS = 32
 1:32 (33 ms)  
DSWDTPS = 128
 1:128 (132 ms)  
DSWDTPS = 512
 1:512 (528 ms)  
DSWDTPS = 2048
 1:2,048 (2.1 seconds)  
DSWDTPS = 8192
 1:8,192 (8.5 seconds)  
DSWDTPS = K32
 1:32,768 (34 seconds)  
DSWDTPS = K131
 1:131,072 (135 seconds)  
DSWDTPS = K524
 1:524,288 (9 minutes)  
DSWDTPS = M2
 1:2,097,152 (36 minutes)  
DSWDTPS = M8
 1:8,388,608 (2.4 hours)  
DSWDTPS = M33
 1:33,554,432 (9.6 hours)  
DSWDTPS = M134
 1:134,217,728 (38.5 hours)  
DSWDTPS = M536
 1:536,870,912 (6.4 days)  
DSWDTPS = G2
 1:2,147,483,648 (25.7 days)
```

However, on PIC18F87J11 I do not see similar configurations. **Does that mean I can not put the PIC into deep sleep?**

Comment: The phrase "Deep Sleep" occurs only once in that datasheet, and it appears to be a mistake.

Comment: so deep sleep is not supported, you would say?

Comment: Based on that information, your guess is as good as mine. I'm pretty sure if it supported a feature though, that feature would be in the datasheet.

Comment: I am almost positive that deep sleep is not supported, I looked at the other pic datasheet and it talks about deep sleep, unlike the PIC I have.

Comment: The [46J50](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en539708) page mentions a "15nA Deep Sleep mode", where again, the [87J11](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en027149) page does not.

Comment: And the [46J50 datahseet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39931d.pdf) has a whole section on deep sleep, where the the 87J11 does not. I think it's safe to say your part does not support deep sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 **  Author: Dan1138
 **  Date: 2011-AUGUST-14
 **  File: main.c 
 **  Target: PIC18F46J50
 **  OS: Win7, 64-bit
 **  MPLAB: 8.73a
 **  Compiler: C18v3.40
 **  Description: 
 **    Sleep mode example that toggles RA0
 **    output bit on wake up from sleep.
 **
 **    If deep sleep mode is working RA0 changes every 8.5 seconds.
 **    If sleep mode is working RA0 changes every 1.024 seconds.
 */

 #include <p18cxxx.h> 

 #pragma config WDTEN = OFF          /* Disabled - Controlled by SWDTEN bit                                                       */
 #pragma config PLLDIV = 2           /* Divide by 2 (8 MHz oscillator input)                                                      */
 #pragma config STVREN = ON          /* Reset on stack overflow/underflow enabled                                                 */
 #pragma config XINST = OFF          /* Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode)              */
 #pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1        /* No CPU system clock divide                                                                */
 #pragma config CP0 = OFF            /* Program memory is not code-protected                                                      */
 #pragma config OSC = INTOSCPLL      /* INTOSC with PLL enabled(S/W control), port function on RA6 and RA7, INTOSCPLL used by USB */
 #pragma config T1DIG = OFF          /* Secondary Oscillator clock source may not be selected                                     */
 #pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF        /* Timer1 oscillator configured for higher power operation                                   */
 #pragma config FCMEN = OFF          /* Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled                                                          */
 #pragma config IESO = OFF           /* Two-Speed Start-up disabled                                                               */
 #pragma config WDTPS = 1            /* 1:1                                                                                       */
 #pragma config DSWDTOSC = INTOSCREF /* DSWDT uses INTOSC/INTRC as reference clock                                                */
 #pragma config RTCOSC = T1OSCREF    /* RTCC uses T1OSC/T1CKI as reference clock                                                  */
 #pragma config DSBOREN = OFF        /* Zero-Power BOR disabled in Deep Sleep (does not affect operation in non-Deep Sleep modes) */
 #pragma config DSWDTEN = ON         /* Deep Sleep Watchdog Timer Enabled                                                         */
 #pragma config DSWDTPS = 8192       /* 1:8,192 (8.5 seconds)                                                                     */
 #pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF        /* The IOLOCK bit (PPSCON<0>) can be set and cleared as needed                               */
 #pragma config MSSP7B_EN = MSK7     /* 7 Bit address masking                                                                     */
 #pragma config WPFP = PAGE_31      /* Write Protect Program Flash Page 31                                                       */
 #pragma config WPEND = PAGE_WPFP    /* Write/Erase protect Flash Memory pages starting at page WPFP[5:0]                         */
 #pragma config WPCFG = OFF          /* Write/Erase Protection of last page Disabled                                              */
 #pragma config WPDIS = OFF          /* WPFP[5:0], WPEND, and WPCFG bits ignored                                                  */

 void
 InterruptHandlerHigh (
     void
     );

 void 
 InterruptHandlerLow (
     void
     );

 /*
 ** High priority interrupt vector
 */

 #pragma code InterruptVectorHigh = 0x08
 void
 InterruptVectorHigh (void)
 {
    _asm  goto InterruptHandlerHigh  _endasm
 }

 /*
 ** Low priority interrupt vector
 */
 #pragma code InterruptVectorLow=0x18 
 void 
 InterruptVectorLow (void) 
 {
     _asm goto InterruptHandlerLow _endasm 
 }

 /* return to the default code section */ 
 #pragma code 

 /*
 **   High priority interrupt handlers
 */

 #pragma interrupt InterruptHandlerHigh

 void
 InterruptHandlerHigh (
     void
     )
 {
     /* hang here if we get an unhandled interrupt */
     for( ; ; );
 }

 /*
 ** Low priority interrupt handlers
 */
 #pragma interruptlow InterruptHandlerLow

 void 
 InterruptHandlerLow (
     void
     )
 { 
     /* hang here if we get an unhandled interrupt */
     for( ; ; );
 }

 /*
 ** Initialize this PIC hardware
 */
 void
 PICInit(
     void
     )
 {
     OSCCON = 0x70;          /* Use Primary clock source selected by config bits */
     OSCTUNEbits.PLLEN = 1;  /* Use PLL to make Fosc clock run at 48MHz */

     ANCON0  = 0xFF;         /* Turn off all analog inputs */
     ANCON1  = 0x1F;
     CM1CON  = 0x00;
     CM2CON  = 0x00;

 /*  UnLock Registers */
  EECON2 = 0x55;
  EECON2 = 0xAA;
  PPSCONbits.IOLOCK = 0;
 /*  Unlock ends */

     RPINR1  = 0x1F;         /* INT1    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR2  = 0x1F;         /* INT2    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR3  = 0x1F;         /* INT3    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR4  = 0x1F;         /* T0CLKI  <= Not mapped */
     RPINR6  = 0x1F;         /* T3CKI   <= Not mapped */
     RPINR7  = 0x1F;         /* CCP1    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR8  = 0x1F;         /* CCP2    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR12 = 0x1F;         /* T1G     <= Not mapped */
     RPINR13 = 0x1F;         /* T3G     <= Not mapped */
     RPINR16 = 0x1F;         /* RX2/DT2 <= Not mapped */
     RPINR17 = 0x1F;         /* CK2     <= Not mapped */
     RPINR21 = 0x1F;         /* SDI2    <= Not mapped */
     RPINR22 = 0x1F;         /* SCK2IN  <= Not mapped */
     RPINR23 = 0x1F;         /* SS2IN   <= Not mapped */
     RPINR24 = 0x1F;         /* FLT0    <= Not mapped */

     RPOR0   = 0x00;         /* unmap all outputs */
     RPOR1   = 0x00;
     RPOR2   = 0x00;
     RPOR3   = 0x00;
     RPOR4   = 0x00;
     RPOR5   = 0x00;
     RPOR6   = 0x00;
     RPOR7   = 0x00;
     RPOR8   = 0x00;
     RPOR9   = 0x00;
     RPOR10  = 0x00;
     RPOR11  = 0x00;
     RPOR12  = 0x00;
     RPOR13  = 0x00;
     RPOR17  = 0x00;
     RPOR18  = 0x00;
     RPOR19  = 0x00;
     RPOR20  = 0x00;
     RPOR21  = 0x00;
     RPOR22  = 0x00;
     RPOR23  = 0x00;
     RPOR24  = 0x00;

 /*  Lock Registers */
  EECON2 = 0x55;
  EECON2 = 0xAA;
  PPSCONbits.IOLOCK = 1;
 /*  Lock Registers ends */

     TRISA   = 0xFF;         /*RA0-7 are digital inputs */
     TRISB   = 0xFF;         /*RB0-7 are digital inputs */
     TRISC   = 0xFF;         /*RC0-7 are digital inputs */
     TRISD   = 0xFF;         /*RD0-7 are digital inputs */
     TRISE   = 0xFF;         /*RE0-2 are digital inputs */

     RCONbits.IPEN = 1;      /* Enable High/Low interrupt priority model. */

     if(WDTCONbits.DS)
     {
         /* handle stuff specific to wake up from deep sleep */

         /* Make RA0 an out bit */
         TRISA &= ~0x01; 
         LATA  &= ~0x01; 
     }
     WDTCONbits.DS = 0;

     if(DSCONLbits.RELEASE)
     {
         /* restore LATA state from before deep sleep wakup */
         TRISA &= ~0x01; 
         LATA = PORTA;

         /* clear deep sleep I/O config lock out */
         DSCONLbits.RELEASE = 0; 
     }
     else
     {
         /* Make RA0 an out bit */
         TRISA &= ~0x01; 
         LATA  &= ~0x01; 
     }
 }

 void
 main( 
     void 
     )
 {
     /* Disable interrupts */
     INTCONbits.GIEH = 0;

     /* Initial this hardware */
     PICInit();

     ClrWdt();

     /* toggle output bit RA0 on wake from deep sleep */
     LATA ^= 0x01; 

     /* prepare to enter deep sleep */
     INTCONbits.GIEH = 0;    /* disable interrupts */
     WDTCONbits.SWDTEN = 1;  /* turn on the watch dog timer */
     DSCONLbits.ULPWDIS = 1; /* disable ULP wake up */
     DSCONLbits.DSBOR = 0;   /* disable Brownout wake up */
     DSCONHbits.DSULPEN = 0; /* disable ULP pull up */
     DSCONHbits.RTCWDIS = 1; /* disable RTCC wake up */
     WDTCONbits.REGSLP = 1;  /* turn off core regulator for deep sleep */
     OSCCONbits.IDLEN = 0;   /* enter sleep mode, not idle */

     /* Check the generated code, the SLEEP instruction 
     ** must be the next instruction after the DSEN bit
     ** is set in the DSCONH register.
     ** If not you must use inline assembly or call
     ** an assembly function to enter deep sleep
     */
     /* go to deep sleep, DSWDT or reset is the only way out in this demo */
     DSCONHbits.DSEN = 1;
     Sleep();

     /* wait here forever */
     /* do a conventional sleep mode if we did not enter deep sleep */
     for( ; ; )
     {
         if(!DSCONHbits.DSEN)
         {   
             Sleep();    /* go to sleep */
             Nop();      /* in general it's best to do nothing for one or */
             Nop();      /* two instruction cycles after a WDT wake up    */
             /* toggle output bit RA0 on wake from sleep */
             LATA ^= 0x01; 
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Comment: Also, since the shown code carries an authors name, please double check that you have the right to publish it here. If this is copied from somewhere, consider explaining the basic core of the solution and linking to the source.